# Creating new pointer object in loop

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

Say I do something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //create a pointer object using new
    //use the object
}
```

Do I need to delete the pointer object after using it in the loop?
I was thinking like, if I didn't delete it, it will keep creating a new object for 10 times and the object just hang in there after that, eating resources.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for every `new` there needs to be a corresponding `delete`. (And a `delete[]` for every `new[]`.)

However, the C++ way would be to ***avoid dynamic*** storage as much as possible and rather employ ***local, automatic variables***:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    some_class object;
    //use object
} // object gets destroyed here automatically
```

If you need to allocate that object dynamically (which I doubt, but there are such cases), then ***use a smart pointer***. A smart pointer will execute the `delete` for you, no matter which way you leave the scope it belongs to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    smart_ptr<some_class> object(new some_class());
    //use object
} // object gets destroyed here automatically
```

The current standard only knows one smart pointer, named `std::auto_ptr`, which would would do what you need in this case. The next standard will come with several more, among them a replacement for `std::auto_ptr`, named `std::unique_ptr`, and one with shared ownership semantic, named `std::shared_ptr`. Your compiler/std lib might actually already support them. If not, you can find them among the many great libraries to be found at [boost](http://www.boost.org).

---

BTW, note that I have replaced your `i++` with `++i`. In case of an `int` this doesn't make any difference in your scenario, but there are types for which `i++` might create an unnecessary copy. (If efficiency wouldn't concern you, why program in C++?)

Answer (score 4):

Yep.

You must delete something that you new'ed when you no longer need it, otherwise you'll get a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes technically you need to delete them.

But. We have this amazing thing called smart pointers that do this auto-magically.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::auto_ptr<int> x(new int(10));

    // automatically deleted after each iteration.
}
```

Comment: I dont think that declaratin will compile.  You need to do `auto_ptr<> x(new int)`

Comment: @FredOverflow, you're incorrect in this case. @Martin is dynamically allocating a single int and initializing it to 10, not allocating an array of 10 ints.

Comment: @Nathan: Indeed I am! Thanks for pointing it out, +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you were so inclined you could use a smart pointer (something like Boost's shared_pointer) and then as soon as the pointer went out of scope for the final time the object would automatically be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to delete it. But doing a new/delete every iteration of the loop may not be the best option -- you need to provide more context to get better advice.