# Do I need to call unlock() at the end of the loop (for a local unique_lock)?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, mutex, stack-unwinding

Is this:

```
std::mutex mutex;
for () {
    std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex);
    // do something
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Equivalent to this in terms of releasing and acquiring the lock every iteration of the for loop?

```
std::mutex mutex;
for () {
    std::unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex);
    // do something
}
```

Related questions:

1. [Is using unique_lock in new scope equivalent to unlock call at the end of work with shared resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683326/is-using-unique-lock-in-new-scope-equivalent-to-unlock-call-at-the-end-of-work-w)
2. [boost scoped_lock on mutex in while(1) loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729606/boost-scoped-lock-on-mutex-in-while1-loop)
3. [Creating new pointer object in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219142/creating-new-pointer-object-in-loop)
4. [Reusing a unique_lock in a consumer loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415874/reusing-a-unique-lock-in-a-consumer-loop)

Comment: `std::unique_lock`'s constructor acquires the lock, and its destructor unlocks it. This is a core principle of RAII style programming. So yes, these two are codes are equivalent. You don't need to `unlock()` manually, just let the `lock` go out of scope.

Comment: No, it's RAII. It does it for you. (There are very specific cases you should call unlock, but this is not one of them)

Comment: Consider using [scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) unless you have compelling reasons not to.